# R Dumbbell chart with legend, unable to sort y-axis

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a dumbbell chart in R that includes a legend and the ability to sort by a value other than the y-axis.

I can get these requirements individually in 2 separate plots but unable to use both features in one chart.

Here's the script showing the plot with legend and no custom sorting:

```
library(ggalt)
df <- data.frame(trt=LETTERS[1:5], l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))
df2 = tidyr::gather(df, group, value, -trt)
ggplot(df, aes(y = trt))+ 
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = value, color = group), size = 3) +
  geom_dumbbell(aes(x = l, xend = r), size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue") )
```

Here's the script showing the plot with no legend and custom sorting:

```
library(ggalt)
df <- data.frame(trt=LETTERS[1:5], l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))
ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(trt,-l), x=l, xend=r)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(aes(x = l, xend = r), size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue") )
```

When i try to add the two together I receive an error "Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  arguments must have same length"  below is the script i'm using:

```
library(ggalt)
df <- data.frame(trt=LETTERS[1:5], l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))
df2 = tidyr::gather(df, group, value, -trt)
ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(trt,-l), x=l, xend=r)) + 
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = value, color = group), size = 3) +
  geom_dumbbell(aes(x = l, xend = r), size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue") )
```

Any ideas how to correct this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure this out.

Simply adding in the lines:

```
  geom_point(size=5, aes(x = r, color = "Blue"))+
  geom_point(size=5, aes(x = l, color = "Red"))+
```

Full script:

```
library(ggalt)
df <- data.frame(trt=LETTERS[1:5], l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))
ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(trt,-l), x=l, xend=r)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(aes(x = l, xend = r), size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +

  geom_point(size=5, aes(x = r, color = "Blue"))+
  geom_point(size=5, aes(x = l, color = "Red"))+

  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue") )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Reformat data:
df2<-df %>% mutate("key"="trt")
df3<-df2 %>% arrange(desc(l))
df2$trt<-factor(df2$trt,df3$trt)

#Plot using dumbbell R package (v0.11)

dumbbell::dumbbell(df2,id="trt", key="key", column1="l", column2="r", lab1 = "l", lab2="r",delt=1, pt_val = 1, arrow = 1, textsize = 3) + xlim(9,83)
```

[image: dumbbell R package v0.11]